# Groovy WSClient and document/literal WS

Tags: java, web-services, groovy

I have a WS avaialbel @ http://domain.com/Service?wsdl. The wsdl imports multiple XSD definitions. When I tried to invoke the service as shown below, i am getting an exception saying it is unable to locate the xsd's on server which is fine as the xsd's are not present there. My question is how to tell WSClient resolve the xsd's from classpath or file system and ignore to get them from server?

```
def proxy = new WSClient("http://domain/Service?wsdl", this.class.classLoader)
        proxy.initialize()



Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:52)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error compiling schema from WSDL at {http://domain/Service/IcTransactionService?wsdl}: http://domain/Service/RequestImpl1-0.xsd
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://domain/Service/RequestImpl1-0.xsd
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://domain/Service/RequestImpl1-0.xsd
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1434)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:383)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the WSDL & XSDs in **a**
   folder and replace all remote XSD
   references in WSDL with their local
   counterpart[Relative Path].
2. Generate WS client and use that.

Tested many times with Axis, Metro & XFire

Please feel comfortable to getback in case of any trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the post but I already know that this solution works. I am wondering if I can provide the the schema's to the client in some manner.

Comment: @Pangea You can bundle those schemas along with your client jar.